# printf not working... JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this method in my code to print for a clock.  I am still only getting 1 digit of an output even though i need 2.  There are purposely no params.  I am trying to get the format 12:01:50 PM

```
     public void printStandard() {
         if (hrs < 12) {
             System.out.printf("%2d:%2d:%2d AM%n", hrs, mins, secs);
         } else {
             System.out.printf("%2d:%2d:%2d PM%n", hrs - 12, mins, secs);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `%02d` instead to have `07` instead of `7` in your time `String`. It will add padding of `0` in the number if number is less than two *digits*.

***i.e***

```
System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d AM%n", 7, 1, 5);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
07:01:05 AM
```

*NOTE :* You can also take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) if you are working with `Date`.